# Changed ROS_PACKAGE_PATH - how do I repair this?

Tags: ros-package-path, ros-jade, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Short version:** I broke my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, and now I don't know how to get my workspace to work again. I'm using rosbuild, not catkin, and jade; on ubuntu.

**Long version:**

I'm pretty much completely new to ros, and I have been working on an existing project from a coworker.
This is using rosbuild instead of catkin, and the workspace consists of a number of different packages.

Now, I have been having a lot of trouble getting another package to work with this (which was by another coworker and was build using catkin...). I've been googling and trying things and ... somehow I think I changed my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.
I think what I did is that I ran a `source` command that's intended for catkin, which broke the whole thing.
When I try to build any of the packages that worked before, it doesn't work since it tells me that this is not a package. When I `echo ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` I get `/opt/ros/jade/share:/opt/ros/jade/stacks`.

Now, I found this answer http://answers.ros.org/question/70435/confusion-with-ros_package_path/, which has been helpful in at least understanding what the problem was. So I tried `export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/user/this_project/this_workspace:/opt/ros/jade/share:/opt/ros/jade/stacks`. This did work (in that it changed the package path), but I still can't compile anything, since it doesn't recognize any of the packages as packages. Which makes sense I guess, because the path I added is not the path of one package, but the path of the directory where all my packages are!
But how do I add the directory with all the packages? And how do I make it so that it recognizes new packages again in the future?

I also found a number of answers that mentioned adding the path of the workspace to a bashrc file. What is that? Where do I find it?
The folder that should be the workspace only has other folders, which are the different packages, and no files at all. I'm also not sure what exactly I should add to it if I could find it.

*Bottom line: I have no idea what I'm doing here, and I'm getting a bit panicked.*
I also don't have anybody I could ask (yesterday I asked another coworker to help me with the previous problem, who was involved in setting this whole project up - and we ended up breaking the whole thing altogether, so that I had to reset everything to the last git commit. And now I fear I've broken the whole ros installation!)
Anyway - I'd be very, very grateful if anybody can help me repair this mess!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244240/changed-ros_package_path---how-do-i-repair-this?/) by [Zaunkönig](https://answers.ros.org/users/27980/zaunk%C3%B6nig/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-09-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) on 2016-09-22**:
~/.bashrc is a file that bash runs every time you open a bash shell. It means adding the "export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=..." command to ~/.bashrc, to make iso it run every time the terminal opened. If setting ROS_PACKAGE_PATH didn't fix your problem, adding it to your bashrc certainly won't fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general you first source the "global" setup, then the "workspace" setup:

```
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
source ~/your_catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

The first command (re)sets the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` to your ROS distribution.

The latter command will prepend the "src" directory of the catkin workspace to the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`

As sloretz writes, if you put these commands in your ~/.bashrc, they are executed in every bash you start.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2016-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0